# ¿Como puedo imprimir solo numeros pares o impares de una tabla de multiplicar?

Tags: python, funciones, excepciones

Tengo unas dudas acerca de un problema que me dejaron, en el cual me pidieron lo siguiente:

> Hacer un programa que imprima en pantalla menu "Tabla de Multiplicar"
> con la siguientes opciones:
>
> - Ingresar rango de números.
> - Imprimir Tabla de multiplicar sólo números pares del rango.
> - Imprimir Tabla de multiplicar sólo números impares del rango.
> - Ingrese número para Imprimir su tabla de multiplicar.
> - Salir
> - Controlar las *excepciones*
> - Utilizar función *main* y varias funciones.

Este es mi código.

```
def num():
    
    table_of = int(input("Ingresa un numero: "))


    l_res = len(str(table_of*12))


    print(f"\n\nTabla de multiplicar de {table_of}:")
    print()

    for multiple in range(1, 10):
        print(f'{table_of} \N{MULTIPLICATION SIGN} {multiple} = {table_of*multiple:{l_res}}')
        print()

def fin():
    print('\n\n\n fin del programa')
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    num()
    fin()
```

Comment: ¿Cuales son las dudas?

Answer (score 0):

Para poder separar cuando el programa llama `print()`con números pares o impares, necesitas separar cada caso, primero imprimir para los múltiplos pares y después los impares.

Puedes yo veo útil separar la lógica en 2 funciones adicionales

- `obtener_multiplos(tipo)`: devuelve una lista de números pares o impares
- `imprimir_tabla(numero, lista_numeros)`: se encarga de imprimir la tabla para cada uno de los casos.

Y para la excepción en este caso la puedes llamar primero verificando si el número ingresado es un numero entero o `int` con `isinstance(numero, int)` y al final puedes llamar la función con un bloque `try / except` para poder mandar un mensaje personalizado en la exepción, cuando ingresan algo que no sea un número entero.

```
def tabla_de_multiplicar(numero):
    if not isinstance(numero, int):
        raise ValueError

    def obtener_multiplos(tipo):
        match tipo:
            case "par":
                return [numero_ for numero_ in range(1, 10) if numero_ % 2 == 0]
            case "impar":
                return [numero_ for numero_ in range(1, 10) if numero_ % 2 != 0]

    def imprimir_tabla(numero, lista_numeros):
        for multiplo in lista_numeros:
            print(
                f"{numero} \N{MULTIPLICATION SIGN} {multiplo} = {numero * multiplo}\n"
            )

    print(f"\nTabla de multiplicar del {numero} para números pares\n")
    print(imprimir_tabla(numero, obtener_multiplos("par")))
    print()
    print(f"\nTabla de multiplicar del {numero} para números impares\n")
    print(imprimir_tabla(numero, obtener_multiplos("impar")))


def fin():
    print("\n\n\n fin del programa")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        tabla_del = int(input("Ingresa un numero: "))
        tabla_de_multiplicar(tabla_del)
        fin()
    except ValueError as e:
        raise Exception("Debe ingresar un número entero") from e
```